# ESP32-S2 JTAG programing problems

Tags: esp32, jtag, eclipse

**A bit of introduction:**

I am using [ESP32-S2](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Espressif-Systems/ESP32-S2-WROOM-IM22S2H3200UH3Q0?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu3sxpa5v1qrl%2FYtpu2q02I6vef1xWTKLA%3D) module with custom PCB and I want to use J-TAG for programming and debugging with ESP-PROG. I am using Eclipse with ESP-IDF plugin (version 4.4) installed, following [this](https://github.com/espressif/idf-eclipse-plugin/blob/master/README.md) instructions.

[image: ESP32-S2 pinout and connections]

[image: J-TAG connections]

**Problem**

I am having problems with uploadiong code:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger  v0.11.0-esp32-20211220 (2021-12-20-15:43)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
3.3
adapter speed: 20000 kHz

Flashing C:/Users/Matevz/Documents/work/esp-idf/esp-idf-v4.4/examples/get-started/blink/build/partition_table/partition-table.bin at 0x8000
Info : ftdi: if you experience problems at higher adapter clocks, try the command "ftdi_tdo_sample_edge falling"
Info : clock speed 20000 kHz
Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all zeroes
Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: esp32s2.cpu: IR capture error; saw 0x00 not 0x01
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Warn : target esp32s2 examination failed
Info : starting gdb server for esp32s2 on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all zeroes
Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: esp32s2.cpu: IR capture error; saw 0x00 not 0x01
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Error: esp32s2_soc_reset: Couldn't halt target before SoC reset
** Flashing Failed **
-1
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
```

It is my first time using J-TAG, and I am not finding anythin useful.

Thanks for all the help in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more debugging I found out that ESP32 module was not working at all. I soldered another board and it is working fine.